# Setting up an association between Users and Bounties in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, associations

Similar to how things work here on Stackoverflow, I'm setting up an app where a user can post a bounty and other users can volunteer to complete it.

The only difference is the user selects who performs the bounty. So for instance if a bounty is created and three people volunteer to complete it the creator can select 1/3, 2/3, or 3/3.

When a bounty is created, it's considered **open**, when the user selects a in progress: **in-progress**, and when complete: **complete**.

For starters how would I setup my associations where a user is the sole owner of a bounty but **other** users belong to the bounty but as `volunteers` and if selected become `participants`. Should this be done as a self-referential association? It seems like setting up two new models may/may not be redundant.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :bounties
end

class Bounty < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

As far as the status of the bounty should I setup three different boolean based columns in the bounties table?

`:open, :in_progess, :complete`

Comment: you need third model for the component on which you want to add bounty and you can create `through` relation using that third model

Answer (score 3):

I would do something like this: this isn't tested so you might need to tweak the options.

```
User
  has_many :owned_bounties, :class_name => "Bounty", :as => :owner
  has_many :bounty_volunteers, :as => :volunteer
  has_many :volunteered_bounties, :through => :bounty_volunteers

Bounty 
  #owner_id, status(can be "open", "in_progress" or "complete")
  belongs_to :owner, :class_name => "User"
  has_many :bounty_volunteers
  has_many :volunteers, :through => :bounty_volunteers, :source => :volunteer
  has_many :participants, :through => :bounty_volunteers, :source => :volunteer, :conditions => ["bounty_volunteers.selected = ?", true]

#join table class
BountyVolunteer
  #bounty_id, volunteer_id, selected(bool)
  belongs_to :bounty
  belongs_to :volunteer, :class_name => "User"
```

So, when you add users as volunteers you are creating BountyVolunteer records.  If they get upgraded to participants you're editing the existing BountyVolunteer record.

Comment: For the third association in the user model what is `volunteered_bounties` referring to? And for the bounty model what does the second association, `has_many :bounty_volunteers` represent? Do the two `have_many through` associations not take care of this ownership scenario?

Comment: `volunteered_bounties` is the join table/model between bounties and users who have volunteered for them.  It's a "rich" join in that it records whether they have been selected as well.

Comment: I see. Now putting this together I ran into this error: `SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: bounties.owner_type: SELECT "bounties".* FROM "bounties" WHERE "bounties"."owner_id" = ? AND "bounties"."owner_type" = ?`

Comment: The above error is returned when I enter something like this: `user.owned_bounties`

Comment: It looks like it thinks that the `bounty.owner` association is polymorphic, that's odd.  Try adding `:foreign_key => :owner_id` to the `belongs_to :owner` association.

Comment: I think I found what was wrong. In the user model it should be `has_many :owned_bounties, :class_name => "Bounty", foreign_key: :owner_id`